# how to globalize method parameter in java?

Tags: java, string, static

I've created method in which I have 2 params.

Here's short description:

```
public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

public String executeRequest(final String content, final String appId) {
     log.info("launching request with appID[{}]", appId);
     /*some code here*/
     .................
     .................
     return content;
}
```

The parameter **appId** is only used in logs. I want to globalize it.
The reason why is that I dont want to put that param in every method I make so how should I do it smartly? or is it even a good idea to do it like that?

basically I would do it like this:

```
public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

public static String applicationId;

public String executeRequest(final String content, final String appId) {

     applicationId = appId;

     log.info("launching request with appID[{}]", applicationId);
     /*some code here*/
     .................
     .................
     return content;
}
```

So my question would be. From the architect point of view is it ok to do it like this? Should I even do it like that?

Comment: Is `appId` constant? If so, you can make it a `public static final` field of a `Constants` class.

Comment: You can always find increasingly elegant ways to solve a problem, but frankly, as far as I am concerned, this is fine. Global access is what `static` variables are designed to be used for.

Comment: @Sweeper yes & no... sort of.. I mean technically it is a constant because you wont change its value during the whole process but the thing is, it is different every time you start this process.

Comment: I would suggest keep it in form of Byte, as you making it public static..

Comment: @Simmant what for?

Comment: I assume every `executeRequest()` call brings its own `appId` (otherwise the method signature wouldn't make sense, as well as the logging). Then what about multi-threading? Can there be multiple `executeRequest()` calls running in parallel? With different `appIds`? On the same `MyClass` instance or on individual ones? You might get the ids mixed up when using a static field.

Comment: @Kayaman application Id is sort important information, and as per example it will be keep on change (which I believe shout not change with every method call), so to not let read with unknow process we can keep it byte[] and where we need we can use it in from of String(byte[]). With current implementation it will be clearly visible as plan text.

Comment: @Simmant that is completely irrelevant here. I hope you're not storing everything as bytes blindly just because you happened to read about the theoretical chance of leaking information with Strings. You might want to read about [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @Kayaman I'm not storing all information byte[], but yeah few information which is important for credentials that I do keep in byte[] and also use SealObject in specific scenarios, and it's not just based on theory few of incident I had witnessed where information lead to vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Simmant sure you have. I bet you and your coworkers write a lot of vulnerable code.

Comment: @Kayaman, I can comment on my case and I use to write, and thankfully after following best practices now I'm pretty well aware of what vulnerability my code can lead to.

Comment: @TomášVárady you mean to say that when you execute a query now with that application, or you execute the same query from the same application tomorrow, the applicationId won't be identical? in that case, there is very little use of an applicationId

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff exactly what I mean... this method can be run multiple times in parallel. So any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem:

- Every invocation of `executeRequest(final String content, final String appId)` brings its own `appId`, I guess it somehow identifies the caller.
- There can be multiple requests running in parallel, in individual threads.
- When logging, you want the log to contain this `appId` that caused the request.
- You don't want to pass this `appId` down the complete call stack to every method where logging might occur.
- There are no recursive calls of `executeRequest(final String content, final String appId)`, at least none where the `appId` differs from the initial one.

I agree that in such a case the `appId` is not worth being added to lots of method signatures, as it's only used for logging and has nothing to do with the regular processing.

Then I'd use a `ThreadLocal<String>`.

```
public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

public static final ThreadLocal<String> appIdHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

public String executeRequest(final String content, final String appId) {
     appIdHolder.set(appId);
     log.info("launching request with appID[{}]", appIdHolder.get());
     /*some code here*/
     .................
     .................
     return content;
}
```

`ThreadLocal` gives you a kind of global variable, with the additional feature that it holds one value per thread. If multiple requests are running in parallel, they won't interfere, as they run on different threads, and so they get individual values.

If you don't have recursive calls of `executeRequest()`, you might consider adding `appIdHolder.remove()` at the end of the method body to free the thread-specific resource if you think that's necessary. But don't do it with recursive calls, because then some nested call would clear the variable, and the remaining code would lack a valid `appId`. `ThreadLocal` does not support stack-like pushing and popping of values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tell that value can change for different process you just use properties

```
public class Constants {

   public static final String APP_ID = System.getProperty("APP_ID");

}
```

and run you jar like `java -jar myjar.jar -DAPP_ID=some value`. Also Eclipse & IDEA allows you to pass parameters via `-D` as well